# Object reference not set to an instance of an object when filling listbox

Tags: c#, listboxitems

```
private void FillListBox()
{
    string ConctingString = "Data Source=AHMED_S_MASHALY;Initial Catalog=BookLibrary;Integrated Security=True";
    string CommandString = "SELECT * FROM BookLibraryTable2";

    SqlConnection Conncting = new SqlConnection(ConctingString);

    Conncting.Open();

    SqlCommand CMD = new SqlCommand(CommandString, Conncting);

    SqlDataReader DR1 = CMD.ExecuteReader();

    while (DR1.Read())
    {
        string listboxvalues = DR1.GetString(1);
        listBox1.Items.Add(listboxvalues);
    }
}
```

this is the error

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in BookLibrary.exe`

Additional information: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

the error appear at this line >>>>>> listBox1.Items.Add(listboxvalues); <<<<<<

Comment: Are you creating the listbox using code? and what is `listBoxValues`?

Comment: Is this a new exception of .NET?

Comment: no I just used drag and drop, and listBox Values are numbers like "9685742152"

Comment: @user3083935 where is `listBoxValues` Created? and what is it, a string?

Comment: Is it possible that `listBox1` is not initialized? Calling any method or property, like `.Items` would return this error if `listBox1` was null.

Comment: @EtherDragon I don't think that is the problem (if it is a drag and drop as the OP says)

Comment: I just made  a program to add books to library. then I made other form to search about ISBN for the book, and when I add the info about the book it saved in sql-server in table I made there, the data type  in sql-server is varchar(max)

Comment: @ChristmasUnicorn what framework is this? We might be dealing with an uninitialized control.

Comment: @EtherDragon IMO, This is a windows form.

Comment: @user3083935 When you debug, what is the value you see for `listboxvalues`, right after the line `string listboxvalues = DR1.GetString(1);` executes?

Comment: the form not even works, I just changed the number 1 to 0 and other items shown in the listbox, I think the problem in the datatype

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because either listBox1 or listBox1.items is null. The easiest way to find out which is to add a breakpoint at that line and examine their values.